# Passing a variable to another file and saving to flat file

Tags: php, variables

I'm in the process of creating a prototype e-commerce website, I'm having problems saving the visitor name to my flat file database "purchases".

```
<body>

    <h1>Confirm Selection</h1>

    <form action="write.php" method="post">
        <table>

            <tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Price</th></tr>

            <?php              
               $visitor = $_POST['visitor'];
               echo "<p>".'Hello '."<b>".$visitor."</b>&nbsp;".'please confirm your purchase(s) below.'."</p>";
            ?>

        </table>
```

The confirm file above creates a variable called $visitor which is whatever the user entered as his/her name in the previous form, I then want to take this variable and once the user has confirmed their selection pass it to the "write.php" file to be processed and written to the purchases file.

Part of my "write.php" file is below.

```
<?php
        if (!($data = file('items.txt'))) {
            echo 'ERROR: Failed to open file! </body></html>';
            exit;
        }

        $now = date(' d/m/y H:i:s ');

        foreach ($_POST as $varname => $varvalue) {
            foreach ($data as $thedata) {
                list($partno, $name, $description, $price, $image) = explode('|', $thedata);
                if ($partno == $varname) {

                    $myFile = "purchases.txt";
                    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file\n");

                    $content = $now . "|" . $partno . "|" . $name . "|" . $price . "\n";

                    if (!(fwrite($fh, $content))) {
                        echo "<p>ERROR: Cannot Write ($myFile)\n</p>";
                        exit;
                    } else {
                        echo "<p>Transaction Completed!</p>";
                        fclose($fh);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: what doesnt work? You say you have problems but what are the problems, what is your output!

Comment: I want to be able to use the $visitor variable in the write.php file

Comment: The write.php file then writes data to the flat file database

Answer (score 0):

If purchase page submit goes to write.php, a hidden variable might work:

```
<form action="write.php" method="post">
    <table>

        <tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Price</th></tr>

        <?php              
        $visitor = $_POST['visitor'];
        echo "<p>".'Hello '."<b>".$visitor."</b>&nbsp;".'please confirm your purchase(s) below.'."</p>";
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="visitor" value="<?=$visitor?>"/> <!-- added line to send visitor -->
    </table>
```

so in your write.php:

```
    if (!($data = file('items.txt'))) {
        echo 'ERROR: Failed to open file! </body></html>';
        exit;
    }
    $visitor = $_REQUEST['visitor']; // added line, now you have visitor
    $now = date(' d/m/y H:i:s ');
```

PS: you might need htmlentities function since the user can enter funny characters for visitor:

```
<input type="hidden" name="visitor" value="<?=htmlentities($visitor)?>">
```